# Change BackGroundColor to an element of the CollectionView

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

In a `CollectionView` I have items with a `DateTime` property, and at startup I select the item that matches today's date

```
public class DateColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (((DateTime)value).Date == DateTime.Today) return Color.Blue;
            return Color.Gray;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

If I press on a different element, the element turns blue,

```
private void SelectedDate_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {               
            var model = (Grid)sender;
            model.BackGroundColor=Color.Blue;
    }
```

**my CollectionView**

```
<CollectionView
     x:Name="ColCalendar"
     RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
     Type=Constant,
     Constant=68}"
     RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
     Type=RelativeToParent,
     Property=Width,
     Factor=1}"
     HeightRequest="45">
     <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
         <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" ItemSpacing="7"/>
     </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
     <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                 <Grid BackgroundColor="{Binding Datet,Converter={StaticResource DateColor}}" RowSpacing="0.1" xct:TouchEffect.NativeAnimation="True" xct:TouchEffect.PressedBackgroundColor="LightGray" xct:TouchEffect.PressedOpacity="0.1">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="9"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="8"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="43"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="SelectedDate_Tapped"/>
                                </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Giorno}" FontSize="8" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

but I would like the one selected automatically to turn gray again.
How could I do?

Comment: According to your description and code, you use DateColorConverter to change collectionview item that match today's date, but what is SelectedDate_Tapped? Don't clear this sentence `I would like the one selected automatically to turn gray again`, please provide your xaml.

Comment: I entered the xaml code

Comment: When you select an item. You are making that item to blue color. And once that item is un-selected then it has to follow you logic like if it is today's date then it should remain blue color else it should revert to gray color again? To be honest your question is not clear.

Comment: Although it matches today's date I would like when another item is selected, the one that was blue I want it to turn gray

Comment: @StefanoAPP If you just want to change selected item color as blue, I think you can try to use [VisualState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/selection#change-selected-item-color)